# Where can I change the BackupWebStorage property in my PhoneGap app?

Tags: cordova, appstore-approval

I created an app using the latest version of `JQuery Mobile` and `PhoneGap` that uses PhoneGap's `Storage API` to store data (around 5k records I guess).

My app was rejected from Apple Store because

> ...app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines...

Couple of months ago, I had published a similar app using an earlier version of PhoneGap on App Store without any issues. I have not done anything new in this app so I am confused what do I have to change to make this to work.

Here are the things that I have already tried

1. I have disabled iCloud support from my provision file for this app.
2. After a lot of digging around, I have found out that the new versions of PhoneGap has a property called `BackupWebStorage` which is set to "`cloud`" by default. I can set it to "`none`" which is ideal for me.

The reference manuals says that this setting has to be set in `cordova.plist` file.
In my project, I could not find the cordova.plist file. I do have a .plist file but it does not have this string in it.

I found that `BackupWebStorage` is available in `config.xml` file but there are couple of `config.xml` files in the project and `BackupWebStorage` is available in only one of those files.

So I am not sure where can I set `BackupWebStorage` to `none` for my project.

Have you come across a similar problem?
Do you have any suggestions on how to prevent my app from backing up the data on iCloud?
If I set `BackupWebStorage` to `none`in config.xml file, then can I build my app using XCode or do I have to use the PhoneGap Build online service to make my app?

Answer (score 8):

Disable it by following steps

- Open Your_Project_Folder/platforms/ios/cordova/defaults.xml
- `preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"`  to `preference
  name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"`
- Save file and Build using cordova build command

Now the problem will get over. :)

Comment: This approach is not sustainable; editing your platforms folder directly will ALWAYS get overwritten when the platform is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your project is MySample, so the Info.plist file will be /MySample/platforms/ios/MySample/MySample-Info.plist, you are free to add/remove keys to the Info.plist file based on your needs. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The config.xml file where you should set BackupWebStorage to none is /MySample/platforms/ios/MySample/config.xml, but be aware that this file is overwritten every time you run CLI command "phonegap build local ios".

Answer (score 0):

Set BackupWebStorage to "none" in the "config.xml" file. The config.xml file is located in your `<project folder>/<appname>` directory.
Then you can build your project with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just add the `BackupWebStorage` option into your main `config.xml` (either on the top level, either inside the `<platform name="ios">` section). This will result in a situation when your ios specific `config.xml` will have two `BackupWebStorage` options, the default `cloud`, and the custom one — `none`. Cordova will use last one.